# Accessing controller scope from directive &function

Tags: angularjs

I have created a simple directive to run a controller function.

I expected that when the function would be called, it would change the data on AppCtrl, but its not happening.

I can't understand why this is a one way binding, or how to make it two way.

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl as appctrl">
  {{appctrl.data}}
  <div dataupdater="appctrl.updateData">Click here to update the data</div>
</div>
```

controller with directive

```
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  var self = this;
  self.data = 'initial data';
  self.updateData = function() {
    var olddata = self.data;
    self.data = 'updated data';
    alert('updated data from "' + olddata + '" to "' + self.data + '"');
  };
});

app.directive('dataupdater', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: { callback: '&dataupdater' },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var handleClick = function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        scope.callback()();
      };
      element.bind('click', handleClick);
    }
  };
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p90oshpq/4/

Comment: You are using function binding so you have to do provide the function expression - `dataupdater="appctrl.updateData()"` and `scope.$apply()` inside the click handler. https://jsfiddle.net/cenpwjg7/

Comment: @PSL Yes you are right, it is clearly stated in [scope documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-life-cycle) "To properly process model modifications the execution has to enter the Angular execution context using the $apply method. Only model modifications which execute inside the $apply method will be properly accounted for by Angular. For example if a directive listens on DOM events, such as ng-click it must evaluate the expression inside the $apply method."